# How to avoid Object reference not set to instance of object error with FirstOrDefault?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

This is my class:

```
public class Employee
{
     public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
     public int Skillssetpoints { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
     public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
}
```

**Code:**

**Scenario 1**:

```
var data=context.Employee.ToList();  //Get all employee records.

//Filter records by employee code(Emp01) and fetch single employee code.for eg:Emp01

var empCode = data.FirstOrDefault(t =>(t.EmployeeCode.Trim() == Model.EmployeeCode.Trim())).EmployeeCode;
```

Here if there is no match found with `Emp01` then getting error object reference not set to instance of object but
fixed this with below code:

```
var Single = data.FirstOrDefault(t =>(t.EmployeeCode.Trim() == Model.EmployeeCode.Trim()));

if(single!=null)
{
   var data=Single.EmployeeCode;
   //Rest other code.
}
```

**Scenario 2**:

```
var data=context.Employee.ToList();  //Get all employee records.

//Fetch List of employee with Employee code:Emp01

var list= data.FirstOrDefault(t =>(t.EmployeeCode.Trim() == Model.EmployeeCode.Trim()));
```

Here in my data object if any `EmployeeCode` is `null` then i am getting this error:

**Error:object reference not set to instance of object**

Fixed with this:

```
var list= data.FirstOrDefault(t => (t.EmployeeCode != null) && (t.EmployeeCode.Trim() == Model.EmployeeCode.Trim()));
```

For my second scenario when i was fetching all the records of employee and doing filter by Employee code i havent addedd this null condition at first because i was having all employee records wihtout any null employee code and everything was working fine but at any point employee code became null and got this error.so in future i want to avoid this mistakes.

So i just want to know that is there any better way to handle both this scenario???

Comment: What is your exact question/problem? You solved the problem on your own. I Did not get what you want.

Comment: @BendEg:but i want something better way to handle this of what i have done because if you look in to my 2nd scenario i have added that null condition after i have encounter that error.If i talk about my second scenario then previously i was getting all Employee records where employee code was not null so everything was working fine but after that when in any records my employee code becomes null then i was getting this error and so after that i have added null condition to handle that.So i just want some better way to handle this

Comment: Probably a waste to use `.ToList()` to load all records into memory when you only want one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For scenario 1, you can write something like this:

```
var employees = context.Employee.ToList();
var data = employees.Where(t => t.EmployeeCode.Trim() == Model.EmployeeCode.Trim())
                    .Select(t => t.EmployeeCode)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

if(data != null)
{
   //Rest other code.
}
```

For scenario 2, you can add an extra where to filter out nulls. However way you slice it, you *will* need to check, but splitting up the filtering is nicer, at least in my opinion:

```
var list= data
          .Where(d => d != null)
          .FirstOrDefault(t => t.EmployeeCode.Trim() == Model.EmployeeCode.Trim());
```

Comment: For second scenario what if you are not aware about employee code can be null at some point when writing this code.you have consider null filter after knowing that ok employee code can be null at some point.

Comment: The person writing the code *should* know that employee code can be null, though. There isn't really a way to avoid the null check, you will need to do it at some point in the code.

Comment: `context.Employee.ToList();` is so wrong. That will return the whole employee table.

Comment: @KosalaW Assuming this is hitting the database, then yes - but that's not a given

Comment: In his code there is a comment that says `//Get all employee records.`

Comment: @KosalaW I agree with you, but it's not a *given* that it comes from a database. It could come from an API for all we know. And if we go down that path, we can completely omit null checks

Comment: can you help me with this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542296/extension-method-to-convert-string-and-create-new-datetime-object-from-it

Answer (score 1):

```
var employees = context.Employee.ToList();
var result = employees.Where(t => (t.EmployeeCode ?? "").Trim() == (Model.EmployeeCode ?? "").Trim())
                    .Select(t => t.EmployeeCode).FirstOrDefault();
```